# Solving a functional equation $\alpha f(x + y) = f(x)f(y)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-derivative, functional-equations, geometric-series

> Suppose a differentiable $f:\mathbb{R}\to(0,∞)$ satisfying $$\alpha f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)\ (\alpha >f(1)).$$
> Express the following sum in terms of $ \alpha$ and $f(1)$:
> $$S=\sum_{i=1}^∞ f(i).$$

Method 1: Geometric progression

Since $0$ is out of the range of $f(x)$ as defined above, I noted that $f(0)=\alpha$.

$\alpha f(2)=f(1)^2 =>f(2)=\dfrac{f(1)^2}{\alpha}$

$ \alpha f(3)=f(2)f(1)=\dfrac{f(1)^3}{\alpha} =>f(3)=\dfrac{f(1)^3}{\alpha^2}$

Similarly, it is easy to note that $f(i) = \dfrac{f(1)^{i}}{\alpha^{i-1}}$

So the above summation is simply a geometric progression which converges since $\dfrac{f(1)}{\alpha}<1$;

$S=\dfrac{\alpha f(1)}{\alpha - f(1)}$

Method 2: Partial Differentiation

$\alpha f'(x+y)=f'(x)f(y)$ (Differentiating wrt x keeping y constant)

Setting $x=0$, and $y=t$, where $t$ is a variable parameter,

$\alpha f'(t) = f'(0)f(t)$

$=>\alpha \ln f(t) = f'(0) t + C$ and since $f(0)=\alpha$,

$=>\ln f(x)=\dfrac{f'(0)}{\alpha}x + \dfrac{C}{\alpha}$

$=> f(x) = Ae^{f'(0)x/\alpha}$ where $A=e^{C/\alpha}$

Plugging $f(1)$ into this function, $A=f(1)e^{-f'(0)/\alpha}$

Hence, the final function is $f(x) = f(1)e^{f'(0)/\alpha(x-1)}$
This will only converge when $f'(0)<0$. How can I prove that using the given condition on $alpha$ and $f(1)$?

And secondly, if I sum up $f(i)$ from $1$ to $∞$ now, the sum becomes;

$S=f(1)[1+e^{f'(0)/\alpha}+e^{2f'(0)/\alpha}+...]$

$=>S=\dfrac{f(1)}{1-e^{f'(0)/\alpha}}$

How can I reconcile this answer with the first one?

EDIT: I corrected the issue with f(0) and f'(0), very very sorry about that.

Comment: Oh, sorry, that's a typo, I meant to write (0,infinity)

Comment: Thanks for highlighting that, I completely missed it

Comment: @lulu we have $\alpha > f(1)$, hence constant functions do not fit.

Comment: Divide by $\alpha^2$ and call $g=f/\alpha$ to simplify the problem.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy  Oh, right.  I mentally changed it to $\alpha≥f(1)$ for whatever reason.  Thanks.

Comment: @jjagmath Wouldn't that ultimately give the same function f(x) that I got in the end, once I absorb the $\alpha^2 term$ appropriately into $f(1)$?

Comment: The part with differentiation is off. You arrive at $\alpha f'(x+y) = f'(x)f(y)$, but you can't really put $x=0$ because we have (for now)  zero knowledge about $f'0)$. Then again, even if we do, we obtain $\alpha f'(t)=f'(0)f(t)$, and not $\alpha f'(t)=f(0)f(t)$ as you wrote =)

Comment: Oh shoot it, that is such a dumb mistake. Thank you very much for catching it

Comment: @Cognoscenti Of course, the answer will be the same, the point is that all the calculations simplify, no need to be carrying the $\alpha$.

Comment: Can you elaborate now, after the edits I've made, @TZakrevskiy? Thank you very much for catching my mistake before

Comment: I'd say that the reconciliation is the equation $S = \dfrac{\alpha f(1)}{\alpha - f(1)} = \dfrac{f(1)}{1-e^{f'(0)/\alpha}}$. In fact, as @jjagmath suggested, it's easier to solve the functional equation $g(x+y)=g(x)g(y)$ for a differentiable $g$, and then you can do whatever you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, full credit to Ms. Kiwi; differentiating the function yields -

$f'(x) = \dfrac {f(1)f'(0)}{\alpha}e^{f'(0)(x-1)/\alpha}$

$\implies f'(0)=\dfrac {f(1)f'(0)}{\alpha}e^{-f'(0)/\alpha}$ and since $f'(0)$ is not equal to $0$ otherwise the function would be a constant function, which is not possible since $\alpha > f(1)$ and the functional relation would imply $f(x)=\alpha$ for all $x$.

Hence, $e^{f'(0)/\alpha} = \dfrac {f(1)} {\alpha} <1 ...(i)$

$\implies f'(0)<0$ (Taking natural log on both sides of the above equality)

which ensures that the sum always converges.
Using $(i)$, we may also rewrite the second sum as;

$S=\dfrac {f(1)}{1-e^{f'(0)/\alpha}}$

$\implies S=\dfrac {f(1)}{1-f(1)/\alpha}$

$\implies S=\dfrac {\alpha f(1)}{\alpha -f(1)}$